# custom ajax call on billing address update magento 2

Tags: checkout, ajax, billing-address, magento2.2.2

I am developing custom payment method, I need to call my js method renderer function when customer update billing address while checkout.

I try to place this call in initialize but my method is not calling.

Any suggestions?